# Magento 2.x - Adding product to quote, but quote is not stored in properly

Tags: magento2, cart, controllers, quote, customer-session

**[edit: one problem solved, one remaining (details at the end of this post)]**

I am trying to add products programmatically to the shopping cart but have problems with storing the cart. I am using the quote object because cart is marked as deprecated (as are load() and save() but i have not found an alternative to them, yet).

I have the following Controller (actually a simplified copy of my controller, but it works in the same way):

```
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Store\Model\Store;
use Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface;

class AddNewProductToCart extends Action

public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        ProductFactory $productFactory,
        Session $customerSession
        Store $store,
        CartRepositoryInterface $cartRepositoryInterface
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this -> resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;

        $this -> session = $customerSession;
        $this -> productFactory = $productFactory;

        $this -> store = $store;
        $this -> cartRepositoryInterface = $cartRepositoryInterface;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $this -> simplifiedExecute();
        die();
    }

    private function simplifiedExecute()
    {
        $products = array(
            0 => array(
                'id' => 173,
                'qty' => 1
            ),
            1 => array(
                'id' => 174,
                'qty' => 3
            )
        );

        $quote = $this -> session -> getQuote();
        $quote -> setStore($this -> store);
        $quote -> setCurrency();
        $this -> cartRepositoryInterface -> save($quote);

        echo '[before simplifiedExecute()] $quote -> getId(): ' . $quote -> getId() . '<br /><br />';

        foreach ($products as $k => $v) {
            $product = $this -> productFactory -> create() -> load($v['id']);
            $quote -> addProduct($product, $v['qty']);
        }
        $quote -> save();

        $items = $quote -> getAllVisibleItems();
        echo 'Testing items from quote via getAllVisibleItems():<br />';
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            echo 'id: ' . $item -> getId() . '<br />';
            echo 'qty: ' . $item -> getQty() . '<br /><br />';
        }

        echo '[after simplifiedExecute()] $quote -> getId(): ' . $quote -> getId() . '<br />';
    }
}
```

and get the following output:

```
[before simplifiedExecute()] $quote -> getId(): 115

Testing items from quote via getAllVisibleItems():
id: 152
qty: 1

id: 153
qty: 3

[after simplifiedExecute()] $quote -> getId(): 115
```

**[update: rewrote this part, due to halfway solving the problem]**

After adding in the CartRepositoryInterface and saving the quote after getQuote() i now have a quote that persists through page refresh.

But the items i added are not showing up on the cart page.
So there must be something else I am missing.

Any answer welcome.